# PhantomJS section name in page header

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS for rendering HTML into PDF. And it's pretty good tool.

It allows to put html in page header. And allow to replace some templates vars like pageNum by current page's number.

But now I need to put some "Section header" into page header for displaying current chapter name in every page.

For example:

```
=====Page 1. Chapter: Quick start=====
<h1>Quick start</h1>
Some text about quick start


=====Page 2. Chapter: Quick start=====
Some text about quick start



=====Page 3. Chapter: Installation=====

<h1>Installation</h1>
Some text about installation

=====Page 2. Chapter: Installation=====

Some text about installation

====
```

Some others tools, like wkhtmltopdf, allow to do it. wkhtmltopdf pass [section] var to header file.

But how to do this in PhantomJS?